# Confusion about sys.exit and SystemExit

Tags: python

I've read several threads here on SO and the python docs on the SystemExit exception.
This thread is not intended to be a duplicate as i did not find the answer in the similar threads.

Does both calling sys.exit() and raising SystemExit do cleanups ? I know sys.exit calls SystemExit, but if you just raise the SystemExit exception, does it do any cleanups for you ? The official python doc wasnt very clear on that. The reason im asking is because a colleague of mine thought that SystemExit was more clear to write in the code and you dont need to import the sys module..but just raising the exception im not sure that any cleanups are being done compared to calling sys.exit which does cleanup before it calls SystemExit from what i know.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote any answers that help you.  Mark one as the answer to be extra nice. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Per the Python 2 docs for [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html), it appears that `sys.exit` and `SystemExit` will both result in normal cleanup.  `os._exit` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sys.exit()` simply raises `SystemExit`.  It's the exception handling being done on the way back up the stack that does cleanup, so both techniques will perform the same clean up.  But you should use `sys.exit` instead of `SystemExit` anyway though: there's no point trying to save one import of sys, that doesn't cost anything.  Calling `sys.exit` is the conventional way to end the Python process.

That said, are you sure you want to be exiting the process explicitly in your code? That makes your functions very difficult to re-use.  Often, people use `sys.exit` when simply returning from the function would work just as well, because it's the main function of the program.

Comment: This isnt entirely correct as the sys.exit() function does from what i know clean up by itself (according to docs for SystemExit, it says that sys.exit calls SystemExit after it has performed clean up but doesnt say anything specifically about when you raise SystemExit itself) but that you have to specify clean up code when raising SystemExit would make sense.

Comment: You are mistaken.  The sys.exit() function literally does nothing other than raise SystemExit.  The documentation for SystemExit does not say it performs cleanup.  I'm not sure what you've read.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: let's elaborate a bit on the answer...

I think it's quite clear in the doc:

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the `SystemExit`
>   exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of `try`
>   statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
>   attempt at an outer level

and

> Since `exit()` ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit
>   the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not
>   intercepted

The missing paragraph in the middle is irrelevant for your question (mostly). Now, this informs us that `sys.exit` is implemented basically by raising `SystemExit`, with an optional argument that is meant for the code that shuts down the virtual machine (to specify exit status code, and message). `SystemExit` is **JUST** a regular exception, which implies a number of things:

1. It can be **caught**. Ie., you can write an `except SystemExit` block and prevent the program from exiting at a certain point.
2. It will trigger all the `finally` blocks that are in the stack at that point. You can use those blocks to do proper cleanup. This includes also `try: finally:` blocks that you may not be aware of, because context handlers may have them on their `__exit__` methods.
3. As the second paragraphs reminds you, only the main thread in the program treats `SystemExit` in a special way. And exceptions don't propagate from one thread to another, so this will only make the system exit if it's triggered from the main thread.

Summarizing, if we simplify a lot, Python's main thread looks like this:

```
 try:
     run_the_main_script()
 except SystemExit as e:
     invoke the registered "atexit" functions (in a LIFO way)
     check e, set exit status, and quit the program
```

Note that this doesn't do any *special* cleanup for you. Python does certain cleanup though: invoking the registered cleanup functions, destroying objects in a controlled way (which will flush buffers, etc).

Comment: then you have not read enough or are misunderstanding. exit is not sys.exit, exit is and should only be used inthe interactive shell when the site module is loaded.

Comment: As I said, [from the documentation of `sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit). The documentation is clear. If you cannot read, it's not my problem. BTW: YOU are responsible for the cleanups, through catching the exception or `finally` blocks (also in the documentation)

Comment: No need to be that rude is it ? I know its stackoverflow but come on man. Yeah i can read and it isnt that clear if the sys.exit() function does any clean up or not the way its written but at least i know now

Comment: Well, I guess telling other people that they can't read or misunderstanding the problem is not rude? Anyway, I read it pretty clear, but I'll elaborate in the answer for you...

Comment: Obviously its rude since i guess you know that a 30 year old person can read ? Saying that he or she cannot is a direct insult of their intelligence. If you are going to try to help people answering question you should understand that not every one interprets the same text in the same way and that not everyone understands every single thing which is the reason to have forums like this

Comment: I was talking about your first comment to this answer. Read it, read what you just said, and then think twice. If you want people to be nice to you, start by being nice yourself